# How to prove $\{ pn:n\in\mathbb{N} \} \cap \{ qn:n\in\mathbb{N} \} \ne \emptyset $ formally?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How would I prove something like this, formally?

If $p$ and $q$ are positive integers, then,

$$\{ pn:n\in\mathbb{N} \} \cap \{ qn:n\in\mathbb{N} \} \ne \emptyset .$$

I need to write this out formally. I am having a hard tie understanding how to prove this, or even get started. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Just as a general rule of thumb, a *set* cannot be proven - a *statement* can.

Comment: In latex, you can use `\{ ... \}` to get curly braces.

Comment: You do not prove sets, that makes no sense. You can prove properties of sets.

Comment: You can suppose it's empty and find a counter example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply say:

$pq \in \{pn| n \in \mathbb N\}$ as $q$ is a natural number.

$pq \in \{qn| n \in \mathbb N\}$ as $p$ is a natural number.

So $pq \in \{pn| n \in \mathbb N\}\cap  \{qn| n \in \mathbb N\}$

So $\{pn| n \in \mathbb N\}\cap  \{qn| n \in \mathbb N\}$ is not empty.

Comment: Thank you for this. What do you mean by step 3? How can I just say that.

Comment: You open your mouth and say it.  If $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ then $x \in A \cap B$.  That's the definition of intersection.  $A \cap B$ is the set of all elements that are in both A and in B.  $pq$ is in one set and it is in the other so it is in the intersection.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** Here is a translation of what the fancy notation is really saying:

> $A$ is the set of all multiples of $p$ and $B$ is the set of all multiples of $q$. The sets $A$ and $B$ must have at least one element in common.

It seems much less difficult after translation, doesn't it?

Comment: How do I prove this using formal proof writing? Like I cannot just show this with an example, can I?

Comment: @Mitchell You sure can. You can prove it using *very* basic number theory.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- Consider $n=q$ in the construction of the left set

Comment: How do I continue after that?

Comment: What number does that suggest is in the left set? Is that number also an element of the right set?

Comment: Well, that would mean pq is in {pn}.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that the intersection of two sets is not empty. That means that you have to find an element that is in both sets. Just give one specific example.